# JQuery nested values within input element. Need to find specific

Tags: jquery

```
<input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_RadButtonMango_ClientState" name="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_RadButtonMango_ClientState" type="hidden" value="{"text":"Mango","value":"Mango","checked":true,"target":"","navigateUrl":"","commandName":"","commandArgument":"","autoPostBack":true,"selectedToggleStateIndex":0,"validationGroup":null,"readOnly":false}" autocomplete="off">
```

**How can we find the value for checked in this case it's true**

I'm able to find all the values but how to get checked

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_RadButtonTrial_ClientState").attr("value")    

{
  "text": "Trial",
  "value":"Trial",
  "**checked":true**,
  "target":"",
  "navigateUrl":"",
  "commandName":"",
  "commandArgument":"",
  "autoPostBack":true,
  "selectedToggleStateIndex":0,
  "validationGroup":null,
  "readOnly":false}"
}
```

Comment: Your value attribute on the input tag is not a valid string.  You can't use the same quote character inside a quoted string that you use to delimit it.  Change the quotes in the string to single quote.  Then, you will be able to get it as a string and if you want it as a javascript object, you will have to call `JSON.parse()` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you need a closing tag:

```
<input></input>
```

second, you can't do this:

```
value="{"text":"Mango","value":"Mango","checked":true,"target":"","navigateUrl":"","commandName":"","commandArgument":"","autoPostBack":true,"selectedToggleStateIndex":0,"validationGroup":null,"readOnly":false}"
```

The double quotes are conflicting with each other. Try wrapping it all in single quotes instead:

```
value='{"text":"Mango","value":"Mango","checked":true,"target":"","navigateUrl":"","commandName":"","commandArgument":"","autoPostBack":true,"selectedToggleStateIndex":0,"validationGroup":null,"readOnly":false}'
```

Now to address the actual question, you need to parse the string from the value attribute as json, and then get the value of checked:

```
var parsedJson = JSON.parse($("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_RadButtonMango_ClientState").attr('value'));

document.write(parsedJson.checked);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. I didn't know it's json

Comment: That's how the json is in SharePoint/Telerik. Not sure why but it works with double quotes as well.